# Using direct function VS std::invoke

Tags: c++, c++17

does this have an effect on performance? Which one makes more sense to use? What are the differences between them?

`void foo(x, y)`

`foo (x, y);`
vs
`std::invoke(foo, x, y);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please [edit] your question to show us what you mean, in code. One simple example with, and one without `std::invoke`.

Comment: It makes sense to use what is more readable for you and clearly shows your intention.

Comment: Your first concern should be the clarity and maintainability of your code. If you're still worried about performance, you should carefully write a benchmark and test the difference on your exact system with optimizations turned on, using e.g. [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark).

Comment: If you are concerned over the performance difference, dump to assembly to investigate the difference in how the calling works and measure the run-time over a million or so calls. I suspect the difference will be so negligible that it likely won't really matter which one is used.

Comment: `std::invoke` exists as a helper function for other library stuff like `std::thread`.  You will probably never have a good reason to use it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your comments <3

Comment: It looks like it is only relevant `"If f is a pointer to member function of class T"` or `"if N == 1 and f is a pointer to data member of class T:"` [std::invoke](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) So, it really wouldn't apply to the generic function provided in your question.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: And the code working with pointer-to-member functions usually knows it.  It's only inside generic template code that it might not be clear whether the correct syntax is `foo(x, y)` or `(x.*foo)(y)` and having the `std::invoke` helper allows the other template not to care.

Comment: That make more sense. More a signal that you intend to call X that is a member of the template as a function.

Answer (score 5):

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Eo6cW6c13) suggests that there's no difference (at least in a simple case).

```
#include <functional>

extern int sum (int a, int b);

int main ()
{
    int x = sum(3, 4);
    int y = std::invoke(sum, 3, 4);
}
```

Assembly output:

```
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     esi, 4        # pushing parameter to call sum
        mov     edi, 3
        call    sum(int, int) # call to sum
        mov     esi, 4        # pushing parameters to call std::invoke sum
        mov     edi, 3
        call    sum(int, int) # calling std::invoke sum
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

As you can see, both assembly instructions are the same, so you can expect exactly the same runtime performance.